# XPath expression on xml file

Tags: python, xml, xpath, flask, lxml

Considering the following XML file:

```
<a>
   <b>
   </b>
   <c>
      <d>content X</d>
   </c>
   <c>
      <d>content Y</d>
   </c>
</a>
```

is there any easy way to parse the XML to make each element have its xpath expression, so I when I do something like `curl http://localhost:5000/home/content?xpath=/a/c/d[2]` it recognizes that I'm referring to the second `<d>` tag?

If there is no easy way, any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: since each `<c>` element in the XML has only one `<d>` child, there won't be no result for `.../c/d[2]`. The index should be for `<c>` instead of `<d>` as in the answer from @dirkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. But you actually don't want the second `<d/>` element, as there is none in the given context. If you apply the position filter (i.e. using `[2]`) it means you want the second `<d/>` element *within* the given `<c/>` element. But every `<c/>` only has one `<d/>`, so you will always yield an empty result.

Hence, the correct XPath would be:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/home/content?xpath=/a/c[2]/d
```